# Bind multiple classes with one condition in Vue

Tags: class, vue.js, data-binding, bind

For example, I had expected something like this to work in that way with using a single condition and setting an array of classes at once:

```
<div v-bind:class="{['bg-red-500','bg-white']:isActive}">
...
</div>
```

**How can I bind multiple classes with a single condition in Vue without using an extra function?**

Answer (score 17):

**This should work:**

```
<div :class="[isActive ? ['bg-red-500','bg-white'] : '']">
 ...
</div>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: Would this work `:class="[isActive && ['bg-red-500', 'bg-white']]"`

Answer (score 3):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    isActive: false
  }
})
```

```css
button {
  outline: none;
}

.class-1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.class-2 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <button 
    :class="{
      'class-1': this.isActive,
      'class-2 ': this.isActive
    }"
    @click="isActive = !isActive"
  >
    set active
  </button>
  
  // OR
  
  <button 
    :class="isActive ? ['class-1', 'class-2'] : []"
    @click="isActive = !isActive"
  >
    set active
  </button>

</div>
```